# Go game board - what is this on the back?

Tags: identify-this-game

The back of my (19×19) go board looks like this:

[image: the back of a go board]

Does anyone know what this is? Is this for a different game?

Answer (score 15):

Looks like a board for [Xiangqi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiangqi), with the river in the middle and the palaces on either end.